# Returning multiple maps in one variable

Tags: dictionary, go

I am working on a XML parser and I have the following problem :

I have this function which gather some tags value, for example movie title and release date :

```
func whatever() map[string]interface{} {

}
```

And I would like it to return something of this form :

```
[map[title:Movie01] map[title:Movie02]]
```

Without changing the return type.

All I have for now is :

```
map[title:Movie01]
```

And obviously I cannot have duplicate "title" key in one single map.

Can you help me on this ? It's been bothering me for a couple of hours now.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question but perhaps you want to return a slice of maps like `[]map[string]interface{}`? Or is it a strict requirement that you not change the function's return value?

Comment: Well, I have to return a map[string]interface{}

Is this possble ?

Comment: I just tested and, the []map[string]interface{} provide what I was looking for. I'll go for it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the record then, as I mentioned in the comments you could try returning a slice of maps such as

```
func whatever() []map[string]interface{} {
}
```

Though depending on your data you might find a better solution in defining an appropriate struct for your domain and returning that.